# Calculate running stock value. Multiply by previous value if it is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help doing some calculation in a query.

I have 2 tables like this example:

***Goods Receipt***

```
date          itemcode      qty      price
-----------------------------------------
01-May-2021   A0001         100      80
05-May-2021   B0001         100      100
15-May-2021   A0001         100      85
20-May-2021   B0001         100      110
```

***Sales***

```
date          itemcode      qty      price
------------------------------------------
03-May-2021   A0001         20       120
06-May-2021   B0001         20       150
10-May-2021   A0001         20       122
10-May-2021   B0001         20       150
14-May-2021   B0001         20       155
15-May-2021   A0001         20       125
17-May-2021   B0001         20       155
18-May-2021   A0001         20       125
20-May-2021   B0001         20       155
22-May-2021   A0001         20       130
25-May-2021   A0001         20       130
25-May-2021   B0001         20       155
28-May-2021   A0001         20       130
```

Now, I came up with this query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(InQty-OutQty) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) as RunningQty, SUM((InQty-OutQty)*BuyPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY Item ORDER BY Date) as RunningValue  FROM  (
    SELECT COALESCE(b.Date, s.Date) as Date, 
        COALESCE(b.Item, s.Item) as Item, 
        COALESCE(b.Qty,0) as InQty, 
        COALESCE(s.Qty,0) AS OutQty, 
        COALESCE(b.Price,0) as BuyPrice, 
        COALESCE(s.Price,0) as SellPrice
    FROM _Buy b
    FULL OUTER JOIN _Sell s ON b.Date = s.Date AND  b.Item = s.Item
) stock
order by Item, Date
```

The result as follows:

```
Date           Item     InQty    OutQty    BuyPrice   SellPrice   RunningQty   RunningValue (*)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-May-21      A0001    100       0        80           0         100           8000
03-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         120          80           8000
10-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         122          60           8000
15-May-21      A0001    100      20        85         125         140          14800
18-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         125         120          14800
22-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         130         100          14800
25-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         130          80          14800
28-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         130          60          14800
05-May-21      B0001    100       0       100           0         100          10000
06-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         150          80          10000
10-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         150          60          10000
14-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         155          40          10000
17-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         155          20          10000
20-May-21      B0001    100      20       110         155         100          18800
25-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         155          80          18800
```

Now the problem is, I don't know how to multiply the `OutQty` to the Cost of Good, because cost per good is always result to zero whenever no `InQty`. To make it more complicated, the Cost of Good is an average. So you need to divide the previous `RunningValue` with `RunningQty` before multiply it with the `OutQty` to get the accurate one.

I need the result to be like this:

```
Date           Item     InQty    OutQty    BuyPrice   SellPrice   RunningQty   RunningValue    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-May-21      A0001    100       0        80           0         100           8000
03-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         120          80           6400
10-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         122          60           4800
15-May-21      A0001    100      20        85         125         140          11700
18-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         125         120          10028.57
22-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         130         100           8357.14
25-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         130          80           6685.74
28-May-21      A0001      0      20         0         130          60           5014.29
05-May-21      B0001    100       0       100           0         100          10000
06-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         150          80           8000
10-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         150          60           6000
14-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         155          40           4000
17-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         155          20           2000
20-May-21      B0001    100      20       110         155         100          11000
25-May-21      B0001      0      20         0         155          80           8800
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use recursive cte to calculate the `RunningValue`.

`RunningQty` is calculated outside of recursive cte. Using `SUM() OVER()`

```
RunningQty = sum(InQty - OutQty) over (partition by [Item] order by [Date])
```

`RunningValue` is calculate inside of recursive cte. Using previous Value + current Buy value - sales value (OutQty X previous runningValue / previous runningQty)

```
RunningValue = r.RunningValue                             -- previous value
             + (c.InQty * c.BuyPrice)                     -- current buy value
             - (c.OutQty * r.RunningValue / r.RunningQty) -- current sales value
```

---

```
with 
cte as
(
    select  rn = row_number() over (partition by [Item] order by [Date]),
            *,
            RunningQty = sum(InQty - OutQty) over (partition by [Item] 
                                                       order by [Date])
    from    tbl
),
rcte as
(
    select  *,
            RunningValue = convert(decimal(18,2), 
                                   (InQty * BuyPrice) - (OutQty * SellPrice))
    from    cte
    where   rn = 1

    union all

    select  c.rn, c.[Date], c.[Item], 
            c.InQty, c.OutQty, c.BuyPrice, c.SellPrice, 
            RunningQty   = r.RunningQty + c.InQty - c.OutQty,
            RunningValue = convert(decimal(18,2), 
                                   r.RunningValue
                                   + (c.InQty * c.BuyPrice)
                                   - (c.OutQty * r.RunningValue / r.RunningQty))
    from    rcte r
            inner join cte c    on  r.[Item]    = c.[Item]
                               and  r.rn        = c.rn - 1

)
select  *
from    rcte
order by [Item], [Date]
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b30cebd07bc0336dfe5eca8b9e181b67)

Comment: Thank you.. Tried the solution, and it worked like a charm. I did a little change over `ROW_NUMBER()` to suit my case, and it worked flawless. Didn't know you can do that with `ROW_NUMBER()`